# Transparent webm video displays solid background color on Chrome for Android 68 on android 9.0

Tags: android, html5-video, webm, alpha-transparency, chrome-for-android

I have simple page with a webm video with transparent background. It works well on desktop. It works well on Chrome for Android version 66 on my android phone running android 9.0 too. But after upgrading to Chrome for Android version 68, the video displays solid background color. I checked the console and no error or warning found.

Chrome 66:

[image: [![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VVbQ.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VVbQ.png)

Chrome 68:

[image]

I tested on Chrome for Android version 68 on other phones which running Android 7 and it works well.

Does anyone know why this happens that and how to resolve it?

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake. It should be `Chrome for Android 68` in the title.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when webm was converted with VP8 codec. I fixed that with converting video with VP9 codec.

Comment: what's the reason?

Comment: I suppose a problem with browser version and codec. In my case, it was not compatible.